# Handling unwanted barcodes in zxing

Tags: android, zxing

I've created an app that uses zxing to handle QR Codes, which is working very well currently.

However, I was looking for a way to handle unwanted codes (QR or not). By unwanted, I mean any code (QR or not) that is not formatted in the way I was looking for to be handled by the standard handler inside zxing.

so in other words:

```
if (scanResult.getFormatName().equals("QR_CODE") && scanResult.getContents().equals(...){
    ...
}
else {
    // handle within zxing
}
```

I've looked around to find some kind of intent schema for this, but I haven't been able to find anything yet. I'd prefer to not have to repackage zxing, as I'd like to try and use the standard zxing implementation (and thus keep my apk size down.)

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. What kind of text are you trying to handle?

Comment: What I'd like to be able to do, is if the app finds a QR code or barcode with data that doesn't match the format its looking for, then to be able to have these QR codes handled by something else.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to scan it and check for / handle the codes that you don't want after you've returned back to your own activity in onActivityResult()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't register handlers or something like that in Barcode Scanner. You can integrate with it by Intent, receive the contents of a scan, and do whatever you like with it.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions